# How to find a list of SNPs that are LD and MAF matched to another list of interest

Tags: genetics

I am a beginner in genetics. I have a list of SNPs of interest, and I'd like to find another list of SNPs that match with LD and MAF. Is there any software to do so? Can this be done in PLINK? I don't really know how to use PLINK.

Comment: I am not a geneticist, but I am having a hard time understanding how finding SNPs is related to Statistics. Care to explain?

Comment: thanks for your comments. the reason to find another group of SNPs  (i.e. group2) in LD with group1, is to be able to perform a permutation test.  In my case, for example, group 1 is QTLs of interest, I'd like to find group2 as a control, in order to generate a permuted null distribution, and then calculate the empirical p value against the null distribution.  But I am not sure how to match MAF and LD!

Comment: Can you please provide more info. Do you have rs# only, or do you have genotype data as well? Please be specific as to what you have tried and exactly where the issue is.

Comment: thank you! I have a large number of mQTLs, i.e over 3000. I want to select genetic SNPs that are in LD with them and also matched for allele frequency. I am not so sure (1) which database is the best to fine them? 1000 genomes pilot, Hapmap 3 or something else? (2) which software i should use? r or plink? (3) when they mean matched for MAF, do they need to be exactly the same? i.e. if MAF for mQTL is 0.19, does the MAF of its linked SNP also have to be 0.19 to be considered a 'match'  or 0.17 is also okay?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions in the comment:

1. I would recommend using 1000Genomes, and restrict to ethnic population if necessary. For population of origin for each sample see:
   ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/integrated_call_samples_v3.20130502.ALL.panel. You can use the `--keep` option in PLINK to analyze only the subset of interest.
2. Use PLINK. R will likely be too slow, unless you use optimized libraries.
3. See answer to your other question on SO here: [Minor allele frequency matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399056/minor-allele-frequency-matching)